# FlipView not work when we pass one viewcontroller to first viewcontrolller of flip view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had take flip view demo from this link : https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView

It's work properly but when we add one view controller pointing to first view controller of flip view demo it get run or flipping correctly,but when we click on any of the view it didn't show fullscreen view. Please give me some idea how to show fullscreen view.

RecipeCollectionViewController where i am calling firstViewController of flip View.
here is my code link- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ubC7-yxm-VUWtZUElDOERvX3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you show images???

Comment: Is there any one to help me?